# Display php echo from php file on a html cordova page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, phonegap

So basically, I'm building a phonegap app, and there's a table that has some information that I have to show on the app (html). I managed to get the login system working, but now I cant figure out how to display an echo from php to my app.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "database") or die("connection error");
$id = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{   
    $select = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$id'"));
    echo $select;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So, basically, the process is the user inputs an ID and clicks a button, and then I get the data from the table row with that ID and display it on the app. Maybe it's with AJAX but I just can't find a way to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Still not able to output the echo in html. Here's the javascript:

```
function yourFunction(id) {
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
    alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
        } else {
    alert(navigator.connection.type);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/StudyBuddy/StudyBuddy/www/yourScript.php',
        data: {
              id: id
        }   
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#data").html(data);
        },      
        error: function(data,r,t){
            alert(t); 
        }
    })
}
}
```

And the html code:

```
<input id="id" type="text" required placeholder='&#61447;  ID'/></span></td>
<input class="button" type="submit" id="button"  value="ID"></td>
    <p id="data"></p>
```

Comment: You cannot use PHP with Cordova.

However, you can use ajax to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PHP with Cordova.

However, you can use ajax to do what you want.

You could do something like :

```
function yourFunction(id) {
    if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
    } else {
        alert(navigator.connection.type);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://yourScript.php',
            data: {
                  id: id
            }   
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },      
            error: function(data,r,t){
                alert(t); 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And your php would look something like :

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "database") or die("connection error");
$id = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{   
    $select = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$id'"));
    echo $select;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Be careful about your `<meta>`
Because you could get an error like this if you are not in https:

```
Security error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': refused to connect to 'website...'because it violates the document's content security policy
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I output it to html now?

Comment: Well, on success in the ajax you have access to what you wanted in the data variable. So just use javascript in your success: function(data){

}

Comment: So shall I do "<p id="data"></p>" in the html?

Comment: Yes, and just modify it with javascript,
Ex with Jquery : $("#data").html(data);

Comment: Do you have Jquery installed ? Try to open the console and see if there are any error in your javascript.

Comment: Yes I do. This is not working. Does it work for you?

Comment: Does the alert(data) show you what you want to display in your <p> or not ?